# Flutter: How to minimize width of DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The `DropdownButton` in Flutter sets its width based on the largest `DropdownMenuItem` from the items it has. That leaves a lot of white space between the item and the arrow if a small item is selected. How do I make the button scale to just fit the selected item's width?

I tried using `Expanded`, some `Flexible` stuff and I still can't make it change its width.

```
DropdownButton(
    value: null,
    hint: Text("Small text"),
    items: ..., //Text widgets that have more text and are larger than the hint
)
```

I am trying to get rid of that space underlined between the `hint` and the arrow: 
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to that? I'm stuck too. It is taking width of the largest dropdown item.

Comment: Same question here. DropdownButton seems to take largest item.

Answer (score 2):

The width is actually determined by the widest item provided by the selectedItemBuilder argument (which uses the items if not defined). With this little trick I managed to have it working:

```
    DropdownButton<T>(
      value: value,
      selectedItemBuilder: (ctx) => [for (final item in items) value], 
      items: items,
      onChanged: (value) => ... update value
```

The selectedItemBuilder in the example produces a list of repeated items (the one corresponding to the selected value). You will need a stateful widget to handle the value.

Comment: The items built by selectedItemBuilder still take up the width of the dropdown, though...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Dropdown button with `ButtonTheme` and add `alignedDropdown = true` like:

```
ButtonTheme(
  alignedDropdown: true,
  child: DropdownButton(...),
)
```

alignedDropdown will match the menu items' width with buttons. Then we need specific width, so wrap ButtonTheme with SizedBox or Container:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 25, // Your width for dropdowns
  child: ButtonTheme(...),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5, 10, 0),
            child: new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 5, 5),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                      bottomRight: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                      topRight: const Radius.circular(5.0))),
              child: new Center(
                  child: new Column(children: [
                new DropdownButton(
                  underline: Text(''),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  hint: new Text('Small text'),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white30,
                  ),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: _selectedLocation,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedLocation = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _locations.map((String location) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: location,
                      child: new Text(
                        location,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: myColour, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ])),
            ))
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly then I have also encountered it and I have a solution. Simply make a Wrap widget as the parent of your DropdownButton. It will make the dropdown menu wrap to the size of the value (not sure how it would react with the null value though)

```
Wrap(children: <Widget>[DropdownButton(
value: null,
hint: Text("Small text"),
items: //Text widgets that have more text and are larger than the hint
)])
```

Answer (score -1):

to remove under line warp Dropdown with DropdownButtonHideUnderline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I managed to remove the whitespace by defining `alignment: Alignment.centerRight`. By default, alignment is set to `Alignment.centerStart`  which forces the Text to align start while the Icon is set to align end. So by aligning the text center right it fills the whitespace that appears between the text and icon. Full Code Sample:

```
DropdownButton(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: .....
     )
```

Comment: That only works if you don't have anything to the left of the text.